# Passing data from a UserControl to another

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form and two custom `UserControl` that I made myself. one control has some buttons that each of these button have theire `Tag` property set to an array of `PointF`. I have another UserControl that has a `ObservableCollection<PointF[]>` that I set its event handler to draw the lines if data is being added to it. This works fine If I put the data points on its own class...just make to sure it works.

No my problem is, having this two control in one form, how can I set the click event of buttons in the first control, to add data points to the second control?

This two controls are both in two different projects in my soloution. and the form that these to controls are being showed in, is also in a different project (it is the launching project of soloution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an event to the first control.

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Control1ButtonClicked;
private void OnClicked()
{
    var handler = Control1ButtonClicked;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnClicked();     
}
```

Add a property to the second control

```
public ObservableCollection<PointF[]> MyPoints{ get; set;};
```

Then in your main application add a listener

```
userControl1.Control1ButtonClicked += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(userControl1_Control1ButtonClicked);

void userControl1_Control1ButtonClicked()
{
    //Do Something to control 2
    userControl2.MyPoints.Add() = //Whatever
}
```

Comment: This property doesn't need to be static if the User Control is an instance?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a public method on the second usercontrol that receive an array of PointF, then inside this method you could add the PointF to your collection.

EDIT: To handle the click event inside the first user control

inside the first usercontrol add the event and the delegate required

```
public delegate void OnClickPointDataEvent(object sender, PointF[] data);
public event OnClickPointDataEvent ClickPointData;
```

then form_load event subscribe to the usercontrol1 event

```
uc1.ClickPointData += new UserControl1.OnClickPointDataEvent(form_subscribe_event);

private void form_subscribe_event(object sender, PointF[] data)
{
    uc2.SomePublicMethod(data);
}
```

and finally, inside the first usercontrol button click call the code that handle the event inside the form

```
....
if(ClickPointData != null)
    ClickPointData(pointf_array);
...
```

Comment: Thats the problem, how can I send data to the second control? There is no way that I can reference that control. Actually I want this mechanism to be hosted inside the first control.

Comment: Let me understand. You have two usercontrol on the same form. The first is called (as an example) `uc1` and the second `uc2` (Both defined and initialized via InitializeComponent). Are you sure you can't call `uc2.SomePublicMethod(uc1.Button.Tag As PointF);`

Comment: That will work I guess, but I ment I want the code for this job to be inside the codes of uc1. I already have a public method on uc2 that receives array of PointF, I want some code in the first control that can respond to the click event for the buttons inside it. Propably an event will be required and it should be subscribed in the form that hosts both controls.

Comment: Updated my answer, added the delegate and the event to insert inside the first usercontrol.