# Usercontrol set TextBox text for other usercontrol

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have two diffrent usercontrol classes. I'm trying to set the textbox text for one usercontrol by another usercontrol. The get of my property is working but the set doesn't do anything. How to solve this? I've posted the related code snippets below.

incidentCategorySearchControl.cs

```
     public partial class incidentCategorySearchControl : UserControl
     {

     private void dataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
      {


       incidentCategoryChange incCatChange = new incidentCategoryChange();
       //textBox1.Text = incCatChange.TextBoxCategory; // works
       incCatChange.TextBoxCategory="test"; // doesn't work

      }
    }
```

incidentCategoryChange.cs

```
    public partial class incidentCategoryChange : UserControl
    {
    public incidentCategoryChange()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string TextBoxCategory
    {
        get { return incidentCategoryTextBox.Text; }
        set { incidentCategoryTextBox.Text = value; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value you get is *default* value, because just a line before you have *constructed* `incidentCategoryChange`. So both getter and setter aren't working.

To communicate between user controls one possibility would be to provide somehow an instance of one, which `TextBox` (or any other property) you want to get/set, to another.

This can be done by having instance saved somewhere, to example, by using `static` property of same class (this require that only **one instance** of that user control is exists, but it's very simple to demonstrate idea):

```
public partial class incidentCategoryChange : UserControl
{
    public static incidentCategoryChange Instance {get; private set;}

    public incidentCategoryChange()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Instance = this;
    }

    public string TextBoxCategory
    {
        get { return incidentCategoryTextBox.Text; }
        set { incidentCategoryTextBox.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

Now you can do

```
incidentCategory.Instance.TextBoxCategory = "test";
```

Another solution would be to use events (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11530264/1997232) question). `incidentCategoryChange` will subscribe to event `CategoryValueChanged(string)` of other user control and in event handler can change the value of `TextBox`.

Comment: I'm not able to try this at the moment, but I will let your hear tommorow. Thnx anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `incCatChange.TextBoxCategory="test";` to  `incCatChange.TextBoxCategory.Text="test";`

Comment: TextBoxCategory is not a textbox, it's a string

Comment: Gives an error string doesn't contain a definition for Text